# Ledger still shows that I have a balance of ETH, but I sent the entire amount twice to Bittrex

Tags: transactions, ledger-nano-s

My Ledger is still showing my entire "balance" of ETH when I open the wallet, but it also shows the twice attempted transfer of the entire amount to Bittrex underneath it. Both times I tried to transfer it said confirmed, but I have yet to see it on Bittrex and am still seeing the full balance on the Ledger. Are my ETH still secure on my Ledger or did I F**k up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the state of your account on the Ethereum blockchain.
To do this, use a block explorer.

> The [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) block explorer is one available option. Once you are on Etherscan, put your public address in the search bar to find your account.

Using the block explorer, your balance can be verify and you will be able to see if your Ledger has successfully initiated your transfer by inspecting the transactions for your account. If no transaction is present, it is likely that your Ledger has failed to broadcast the transaction to the blockchain.

Comment: total noob here, where would I find my public address

Comment: @zukie The public address is the recipient address. Click on receive to get your address. Check my youtube channel for some crypto playlist resources here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4UJ26WkceqONNF5S26OiVw

Comment: Etherscan was the best information on showing why the transactions didn't go through. There's still a fee that is charged for unsuccessful transactions, but I now understand the "gas" from Ledger wallet was not enough. It's unfortunate that information is not relayed on the actual Ledger wallet itself. I wouldn't have been a jack ass and tried to send it a second time

Answer (score 0):

Use myetherwallet to connect. I had the same issue and could not get it resolved with the Chrome extension.

Ripple was also 0 but logging in as a different user on the computer resolved that issue.

I think this is really poor as you put a lot of faith into these devices. They should be inflable. Using chrome extensions is a bit sh1t I think.